# Why does my script that uses twilio run perfectly locally, but throw an error on Python Anywhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, pythonanywhere

My script executes perfectly when I run it locally, but when I execute it on Python Anywhere, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ectobiologist7/desiderius.py", line 68, in <module>
    asendoff()
  File "/home/ectobiologist7/desiderius.py", line 64, in asendoff
    body=billiam,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py", line 122, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 365, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 200, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 152, in make_twilio_request
    resp = make_request(method, uri, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 117, in make_request
    resp, content = http.request(url, method, headers=headers, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1314, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1064, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 987, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1223, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 834, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Now, I've combed through forums both on Stack Overflow and on Python anywhere itself, and none of the solutions I've found have succeeded. One suggestion was that the script wasn't working because a website I was trying to access wasn't on the whitelist, and this is not the case. I tried using a bit of code I found to force PA to use a different proxy, as suggested by a site dev, and that did not work. I also saw the dev recommending that people with this problem instead use Python 2.7. I did that, and still nothing changed. Are there any other possible solutions? Thanks in advance! My code is below.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from datetime import *
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
import ast
#use julian date to calculate days left till summer

# put your own credentials here
def dateelle():
    #use datetime to state date in Month Day, Year format.
    todaylist = date.today().timetuple()
    monthdict = {1:"January ", 2:"February ", 3:"March ", 4:"April ", 5:"May ", 6:"June ", 7:"July ", 8:"August ", 9:"September ", 10:"October ", 11:"November ", 12:"December "}
    month = monthdict[todaylist[1]]
    day = todaylist[2]
    year = todaylist[0]
    ultidate = str(month) + str(day) + ", " + str(year) + " "
    return ultidate
def temple():
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5429522&APPID=0f25c0515e643bc2427f665f88a4d3eb'
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36'
    tri1 = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    tri2 = urllib.request.urlopen(tri1)
    quell = BeautifulSoup(tri2)
    tagwithtemp = int(ast.literal_eval(quell.text)['main']['temp'] * (9/5) - 459.67)
    return tagwithtemp

def daysleft():
    todayy = date.today().timetuple()[7]
    allthatremains = 147 - todayy
    return allthatremains


comp = {0:" You look nice today.",
        1:" Have a good day.",
        2:" Today will be a great day.",
        3:" You are an important person who means much to the world.",
        4: " Someone's day today will be brightened by your presence.",
        5: " Despite the amount of people in the world, your existence matters. :)",
        6: " There may be billions of people on this planet, but you still make a difference."}
billiam = "Good morning! Today is " + dateelle() + "and it is " + str(temple()) + " degrees." + comp[randint(0,6)] + " " + str(daysleft()) + " days left until summer!"

def asendoff():
    global billiam
    ACCOUNT_SID = "***" #the SID, AUTH token, and my phone number are censored
    AUTH_TOKEN = "***"
    nummer = ["***"]
    client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

    for lexis in nummer:
        client.messages.create(
            to=lexis,
            from_="+15026255861",
            body=billiam,
        )

if date.today().timetuple()[6] != 6 and date.today().timetuple()[6] != 7:
    asendoff()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I suspect there's a firewall somewhere that's blocking PythonAnywhere.

Comment: @Barmar On Twilio's end? How would this be fixed?

Comment: No way to tell from here which end it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All external connections from PythonAnywhere free accounts are proxied to prevent abuse.

You need to set the proxy for the connection like this:

```
from twilio.rest.resources import Connection
from twilio.rest.resources.connection import PROXY_TYPE_HTTP

Connection.set_proxy_info(
    "proxy.server",
    3128,
    proxy_type=PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
)
```

However, in Python 3, httplib2 (and therefore [twilio-python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install)) ignores the proxy settings (see the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/wiki/Examples-Python3)) and so tries to make a direct connection to Twilio which is blocked.

Comment: I did already try a proxy but this one looks different so I'll try it! Where exactly in the script should I put this?

Comment: Before you make the connection to twilio

Comment: Got it! For future readers of this, to clarify, you have to add the proxy code AND use Python 2.7. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't import those modules

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There have been [previous reports](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1139/) suggesting PA had older versions of the library. A few months ago we made a [pretty significant change](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/security-update-on-ssl-certificate-validation.html) in our libraries and API to enforce SSL.

If you're using the latest version of the library, there should be no change for you. From the error you posted, I can't exactly tell what version of the library PA are using, but digging a little further, users seem to [suggest you need a proxy](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/3854/).

My suggestion here would be to slightly change your approach and perhaps deploy this to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) (it's free and you will be able to use the exact library version you want). That way, if you see that it works there, you could contact PA and check which library version they have, and you will be able to tell them whether they need an update or not.

Hope this helps you

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- you can run any version of the Twilio library you want on our platform too, using `pip2.7 install --user --upgrade` or a virtualenv.  The problem is the bug in httplib2 that means it ignores proxy settings (required for free PythonAnywhere accounts) -- see Glenn's answer to this question.

Comment: Actually, one thing I should say -- `requests` definitely seems to be a better library to build APIs on than `httplib2`.  We've never had any problems with proxy settings in a `requests`-based library, especially as it picks them up from the standard environment variables rather than requiring the user to configure them in code.  It does clever connection-pooling stuff too, so in theory things can operate faster if your servers support it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that both the console on PA and my local script bother use 5.4.0 and this error still  occurs.

Comment: And in the main post, that link to the solution proxy is the exact on I mentioned in my question that did not work. Sorry!